# DateTime coming as '11.22.2022 09.10.00' and sql update query failing

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server-2016

For one the production system, different date/time format I am getting data time like `11.22.2022 09.10.00` and when try to run below sql query I am getting error `The conversion of a varchar data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value`,

I tried to convert date before querying SQL like `'{ac.LastCollectionTime:MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss}'),")`, but it's not converting.

```
DECLARE @data TABLE(Id uniqueidentifier, Value DateTime) 
INSERT INTO @data VALUES ('57f5a153-3cce-48d4-aa0d-894c14b1a2ab', '11.22.2022 09.10.00')
UPDATE A SET LastCollectionTime = AD.Value
FROM App A INNER JOIN @data AD on AD.Id = A.Id
```

How to fix this issue?

Comment: `11.22.2022` looks strange to me. My calendar does not contain 22 months within the current year

Comment: 11 is month, 22 is date here :)

Comment: Is that a format that SQL server can convert? The error message sounds different - can you convert the date on your own before querying the database?

Comment: With C# code , I tried to convert `'{ac.LastCollectionTime:MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss}'),")` , but still date is coming like this

Comment: I think that you may need to parse the string into a DateTime object.  It doesn't look like any of the default formats (admittedly there's the cultural swapping of month and day to handle) but the time as "09.10.00" doesn't look familiar, I'd expect "09:10:00"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As this is not a date string format SQL Server is aware of out the box, you will either need to adjust your data source to provide an appropriate format or parse out the bits you need manually.

One such way of doing this is as follows:

```
create table d(ds varchar(25));
insert into d values
 ('11.22.2022 09.10.00')
,('11.01.2022 01.01.01');


select d.ds
      ,datetime2fromparts(dp.y,dp.mo,dp.d,dp.h,dp.mi,dp.s,0,0) as dt
from d
  cross apply(values(substring(d.ds,7,4)
                    ,substring(d.ds,1,2)
                    ,substring(d.ds,4,2)
                    ,substring(d.ds,12,2)
                    ,substring(d.ds,15,2)
                    ,substring(d.ds,18,2)
                    )
             ) as dp(y,mo,d,h,mi,s)
```

Which outputs:

| ds | dt |
| --- | --- |
| 11.22.2022 09.10.00 | 2022-11-22 09:10:00 |
| 11.01.2022 01.01.01 | 2022-11-01 01:01:01 |

Comment: Thanks @iamdave for SQL tip. I am able to managed through client code